# Try to set custom validation message with jQuery Remote

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the a form with the following validation setup:

```
$('#form').validate({
            onfocusout: false,
            onkeyup: false,
            onclick: false,
            success: function (){
                $('#username').addClass('input-validation-confirmation');
            }
        });
$('#username').rules("add", {
        onfocusout: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        required: true,
        email: true,                    
        remote: {
            url: function,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                username: function () {
                    return $('#username').val();
                }
            },
            dataFilter: function (responseString) {
                var response = jQuery.parseJSON(responseString);
                currentMessage = response.Message;
                if (response.State == 0) {
                    currentMessage = currentMessage + 0;
                                return false;
                }
                return 'true';
            },
            beforeSend: function (response) {
                showLoadingIndicator($('#username'));
            },
            complete: function () {
                hideLoadingIndicator($('#username'));
            }
        }
});
```

What this is attempting to do is use the same validation elements (in order to work with some other framework) to show both errors and success methods.

My problem is that the success method of my rule gets fired BEFORE the remote validation has completed. I tried setting the message several ways but the custom messages parameter doesn't seem to be called on validation success.

Does anyone know of other methods to use the validation error field for both success and error messages when using a mix of both remote and pattern validation rules?

**Edit:**

I now understand I was expecting a success event at the wrong time. I need an event that is fired once validation has completed (not submitted). Is there any such event?

Comment: I assume you're using http://jqueryvalidation.org/?  If so, it looks like the [remote method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method) is on a per-field basis, and should be a child of the field that is going to trigger a remote check . . .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code...

```
$('#username').rules("add", {
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    required: true,
    email: true,                    
    remote: { ... },
    messages: { ... },
    success: function (label) { ... }
});
```

The problem here is that `onfocusout`, `onkeyup` and `success` are not "rules".  Only individual "rules" and the `messages` option can be placed inside of the `.rules('add')` method.

```
$('#username').rules("add", {
    required: true,
    email: true,                    
    remote: { ... },
    messages: { 
        remote: "custom remote message"
    }
});
```

See documentation for `.rules()` method:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules

`onfocusout`, `onkeyup` and `success` are "options" that only go inside of the `.validate()` method, which is only attached to the `<form>` element.

As far as a "custom" message for `remote`:  [As per the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/), this error message is automatically going to be the message returned from your server... there is no special setup.

---

**EDIT as per comments and updated OP:**

Your code:

```
$('#form').validate({
        onfocusout: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        onclick: false,
        success: function (){
            $('#username').addClass('input-validation-confirmation');
        }
});
```

You stated,  *"Still, with updated code (see above) I never see the success event."*

You've disabled all the events on this form.  The only event left for triggering validation on this field is when the submit button is clicked.  Exactly ***when*** do you expect to "see" `success` fire off?

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/xMhvT/

In other words, `submit` is the only event left to trigger a validation test when you've disabled all the other events.

---

**EDIT based on another OP update:**

> *"I now understand I was expecting a success event at the wrong time. I
>   need an event that is fired once validation has completed (not
>   submitted). Is there any such event?"*

`success` is not an "event".  An "event" is a `click`, `blur`, `keyup`, etc.  (`onkeyup`, `onfocusout` and `onclick` are options that control the events for this plugin)

`success` is a "callback function".  A "callback function" is what happens *upon* the event.

• If you need a "callback function" that fires every time a field passes validation, then you can use `success`.

• If you need a "callback function" that fires when the form passes validation, then you can use `submitHandler`.  However, this is also when the form is submitted.

• If you want to "test" the entire form or a single field to see if it's valid without submitting the form, you can use the `.valid()` "method".

```
$('#username').valid();  // for one field

// or

$('#form').valid();  // for the whole form

// you can also...

if ($('#form').valid()) {
   //do something if form is valid
}
```

This method will fire the test (show the message) and return a boolean value.

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/xMhvT/1/

See: http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Comment: Yeah, that's the weirdest thing. I originally had success setup on the validate() function but that was never being called at all. I moved it to the rules call because I could. That's when it started being called at all.

Comment: @PaulSachs, Perhaps you made some other errors within `.validate()`. `success` is also part of the core functionality of the plugin.  When the plugin is operating, `success` will still be fired whether you've declared it or not.  Otherwise, I don't know how else to help you other than to show the proper way to use this plugin and its methods.

Comment: @PaulSachs, putting `success` within the `rules()` method totally breaks the plugin.  It's firing on page load and when fields are invalid:  http://jsfiddle.net/9AfLa/

Comment: Yes, I see that now. My bad. Still, with updated code (see above) I never see the success event.

Comment: @PaulSachs, show enough code to make a proper demo... still need to see the HTML markup of the form.

Comment: @PaulSachs, see my updated answer.  Since you've disabled every possible event for triggering the validation of this field, you will never see `success` fire until after the submit button is clicked... by then, the data is being sent and the page already being reloaded/redirected.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/xMhvT/

Comment: I have disabled everything due to some other reading I've done with the plugin. I must be mistaken as to what the success event is. I thought the success event is fired when the fields were validated, not submitted. The validation actually still occurs when i tab out. Not actually sure why.

Comment: @PaulSachs, You are correct about _how_ it fires.  **However**, since you've disabled **all other** events, the _only_ event left to trigger the validation is the `submit` event!  "Tabbing out" fires the `onfocusout` event... when `onfocusout` is disabled, tabbing does nothing.  The only way I can get this example to trigger a validation test is by clicking the submit button:  http://jsfiddle.net/xMhvT/

Comment: @PaulSachs, what "reading"?  There is nothing wrong with using these event triggers.  Otherwise, no validation will occur until you try to submit the form.

Comment: Well, I disabled the onkeyup because I would hit the server on every key, and that is inefficient. I read another stackoverflow question (can't find it now) that was seeing two validation events onfocusout and recommended setting it to false that removed one of the events. I'll play around with this some more.

Comment: @PaulSachs, you are correct about that... when using `remote`, you don't want it firing validation on every keystroke.

Answer (score 15):

Use the `remote`, `dataFilter` and `messages` parameters like this:

```
var message = 'Default error message';

$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        element1: {
            remote: {
                url: '/check',
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    element2: function() {
                        return $('.element2').val();
                    }
                },
                dataFilter: function(response) {
                    response = $.parseJSON(response);

                    if (response.status === 'success') return true;
                    else {
                        message = response.error.message;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        element1: {
            remote: function(){ return message; }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am late to answer this question but I think it may help others:

in your php just need to add the following

```
if($rows_matched==1){
          echo (json_encode(false));
        }
        else{
          echo (json_encode(true));
        }
```

and in your js code write the followiing:
$(function(){

```
$('#product_add').validate({
rules:{
  product_sku:{
    remote:{
      url:'check.php',
      type:'POST'
    }
  }
},
messages:{
  product_sku:{
    remote:'already in database'
  }
}
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
dataFilter: function(response) {
                    response = $.parseJSON(response);

                    if (response.status === 'success') return true;
                    else {
                        message = response.error.message;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```